# MakeFile Set Variable at Runtime

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile as follows.. At the first line that says windows.. Then on that same line, I try to set the variable to windows and jmp to $(WinDIR)/$(WinOUT)

How can I do that?

```
windows: ObjDIR=Windows $(WinDIR)/$(WinOUT)
    @echo
    @echo "Finished Making windows.."

clean:
    @echo "    Cleaning Build Files."
    @rm -rf $(BinDIR) $(ObjDIR)

$(WinDIR)/$(WinOUT): $(ObjFiles)
    @echo
    @echo "Linking Object Files.."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um...

```
windows: ObjDIR=Windows

windows: $(WinDIR)/$(WinOUT)
    @echo
    @echo "Finished Making windows.."
```

But I'm not sure you understand how Make works. It won't "jump to" `$(WinDIR)/$(WinOUT)`, it will -- perhaps -- execute the `$(WinDIR)/$(WinOUT)` rule first.

Comment: This is what I meant. It's exactly what I wanted. I figured it out a couple minutes after posting but thank you for clearing up the jump and for posting the answer.